# How to get out of iterate loop when a condition is met?

Tags: loops, haskell

I want to iterate over a function `g` with `iterate`. When I run my code the loop runs infinitely. Is there any possibility to get out of the loop when a condition is met?

Something like `if g x > 100 then stop`.

My code:

```
f x = iterate g x

g x = 2 * x
```

Comment: You can also try until function. http://zvon.org/comp/r/ref-Haskell.html#Functions~Prelude.until

Comment: `take 100 $ f 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you either use `takeWhile (not . p)` for that, equivalent to

```
foldr (\x r -> if (not (p x)) then (x:r) else []) []
```

or sometimes the following is useful,

```
takeUntil p = foldr (\x r -> if (not (p x)) then (x:r) else [x]) []
```

if you want to include the last element into the sequence, as well.

In your case, you'd write `takeWhile (not . (> 100)) . iterate (*2)`, or `takeUntil (> 100) . iterate (*2)`.

`(not . (> 100))` is of course the same as `(<= 100)`.

Comment: What is the point of blank avatar which i see many users switching 
to recently..? Couldn't find anything on meta...

Comment: @Redu No one here has a blank avatar. I think you're having connection problems or something.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yes i guess "or something" is applying here. Strange thing is i see this for "some particular" users in all my computers which are at different locations. Sorry for totally out of topic question though.

Comment: @Redu try https://stackoverflow.com/users/849891/will-ness?tab=profile. btw I used to sometimes - very rarely - have the same problem. I just ignored it, and it went back to normal.

Answer (score 4):

Just flip the condition, and `takeWhile` it holds:

```
f x = takeWhile (<= 100) $ iterate g x
```

Which could also be made point free:

```
f = takeWhile (<= 100) . iterate g
```

This will take from the infinite list that `iterate` returns while the accumulator is less than or equal to 100.