# The most correct way to iterate over a list in haskell, and return the element for which a condition is true

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming

I have a function which takes some argument and calls another function which returns a list of the form [a_1, a_2, ..., a_n].

What I am trying to do is call a predicate p on each item in the list, and return the item for which p(a_i)=True.

If not, then I will recursively repeat the algorithm for all a_i.

The structure is as follows:

```
f :: t -> t
f =  (g t) --this is a list
     (p ?) -- p is a predicate on each element
```

I want to call this  predicate p on each item on the list then return the item if the predicate is true.

If the predicate does not hold for all items, then I recursively call f on each item in the list which I realize will give me multiple "t" which I know how to combine into a single t to match my signature.

I found this:

[How to get out of iterate loop when a condition is met?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47122615/how-to-get-out-of-iterate-loop-when-a-condition-is-met)

But the structure of the condition looks different than what I am trying to do.

Could someone possibly point me to the right direction?

Comment: Unfortunately, this description leaves too much ambiguous to easily answer.  (For example, What's supposed to happen if `a_1` and `a_2` both satisfy the predicate -- is `a_1` returned or are they combined?  What if none of `a_1` through `a_n` satisfy it, but `g a_1` has two elements that satisfy the predicate, and `g a_2` has another?  What sort of "combining" are you talking about?) Can you explain what concrete problem you're trying to solve, even in a simplified form, or give us some concrete examples?

Comment: It might be useful to look at the definition of `filter` from Prelude ([here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#filter)), and adapt it to your needs - it seems to be the key component of what you're trying to do (at least as I understand it). Or cheat and use `find` from `Data.List`.

Comment: You need to improve your question to avoid it being closed, you are far more likely to get a useful answer if your question is very clear.  please review how to ask questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about if you define

```
satisfies:: [t]-> (t -> Bool) -> Maybe t
```

which means that `satisifies` takes a list and a predicate, and returns a [`Maybe` of an element](https://www.google.com/search?q=haskell+maybe). This is one way of indicating that there might not be an element satisfying the predicate (it makes the function *total*, meaning, it is always defined).

Now if the list is empty, the return is `Nothing`:

```
satisfies [] _ = Nothing
```

Finally,

```
satisfies (x:xs) p = case p x of
    True -> Just x
    False -> satisfies xs p
```